# R bar-plot with different variables in multiple columns

Tags: r

I want to create an R bar-plot with different variables in multiple columns, all in one chart. I am only able to do a 2x2 plot with the following code:

```
barplot(table(y = cut$Gender,x = cut$Education))
```

Even so, **Gender** gets stacked on top of **Education**.

[image: Respondents Gender and Education level]

The type of chart I want looks like this:
[image]

My sample dataset is:

```
structure(list(Gender = c("Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", 
"Male", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", 
"Female", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male"), 
    Age = c("45-54 yrs", "35-44 yrs", "25-34 yrs", "25-34 yrs", 
    "25-34 yrs", "45-54 yrs", "25-34 yrs", "25-34 yrs", "25-34 yrs", 
    "35-44 yrs", "18-24 yrs", "25-34 yrs", "25-34 yrs", "55-64 yrs", 
    "35-44 yrs", "35-44 yrs", "35-44 yrs", "45-54 yrs", "35-44 yrs", 
    "45-54 yrs"), Employment = c("Civil servant", "Private sector", 
    "Private sector", "Private sector", "Trader", "Civil servant", 
    "Private sector", "Private sector", "Private sector", "Civil servant", 
    "Student", "Student", "Civil servant", "Retired", "Self-employed", 
    "Private sector", "Civil servant", "Civil servant", "Private sector", 
    "Private sector"), Marriage = c("Married", "Married", "Married", 
    "Married", "Single, never married", "Married", "Married", 
    "Married", "Married", "Married", "Single, never married", 
    "Single, never married", "Married", "Married", "Married", 
    "Married", "Married", "Married", "Married", "Married"), Education = c("Advanced degree", 
    "Advanced degree", "Bachelor's degree", "Bachelor's degree", 
    "Secondary education", "Advanced degree", "Bachelor's degree", 
    "Bachelor's degree", "Secondary education", "Secondary education", 
    "Secondary education", "Secondary education", "Advanced degree", 
    "Bachelor's degree", "Basic education", "Advanced degree", 
    "Advanced degree", "Advanced degree", "Advanced degree", 
    "Advanced degree"), Residence = c("Ashanti", "Ashanti", "Ashanti", 
    "Ashanti", "Ashanti", "Brong-Ahafo", "Brong-Ahafo", "Brong-Ahafo", 
    "Brong-Ahafo", "Brong-Ahafo", "Brong-Ahafo", "Brong-Ahafo", 
    "Central", "Central", "Eastern", "Greater Accra", "Greater Accra", 
    "Greater Accra", "Greater Accra", "Greater Accra"), Experience = c("Never", 
    "Never", "Never", "Never", "Never", "Never", "Never", "Never", 
    "Never", "Never", "Never", "Never", "Never", "Never", "Never", 
    "Never", "Never", "Never", "Never", "Never")), .Names = c("Gender", 
"Age", "Employment", "Marriage", "Education", "Residence", "Experience"
), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach:

First convert the data to long format, here one has two options `melt` from `reshape` package or `gather` from `tidyr`. Here I will use `tidyverse` library 
 which loads many useful packages.

```
library(tidyverse)

 df %>%
      gather(variable, value)
```

Then make a bar plot with ggplot2

```
ggplot()+
     geom_bar(aes(x = variable, fill = value), color = "black" , position = "stack", show.legend = FALSE)
```

To add text annotations we make a `geom_text` layer, the positions of the labels will be determined by `stat = "count"` which calculates a special variable `..count..` corresponding to the top of the bars since this is a bit crude on the plot we can adjust it with `vjust = 1`

```
geom_text(stat = "count", aes(x = variable, label =  value,
                              y = ..count..,
                              group = value),
          position = "stack", vjust = 1)
```

To add percent labels on y axis the usual is `y = (..count..)/sum(..count..)`, however the sum(..count..) is the sum of counts across all variables and is not appropriate here so the easiest solution is to manually label

```
scale_y_continuous(labels =  c("0%", "25%", "50%", "75%", "100%"),
                   breaks = c(0, 5, 10, 15, 20))
```

How it looks all together:

```
library(tidyverse)

 df %>%
  gather(variable, value) %>%
  ggplot()+
  geom_bar(aes(x = variable, fill = value),
           color = " black",
           position = "stack", show.legend = FALSE)+
  geom_text(stat = "count",
             aes(x = variable,
                 label =  value,
                 y = ..count..,
                 group = value),
             position = "stack", vjust = 1) +
scale_y_continuous(labels =  c("0%", "25%", "50%", "75%", "100%"),
                   breaks = c(0, 5, 10, 15, 20))
```

[image]

another option is `y = ..count../sum(..count..)*7` since there are 7 variables

```
df %>%
  gather(variable, value) %>%
  ggplot()+
  geom_bar(aes(x = variable, y = ..count../sum(..count..)*7, fill = value), color= " black", position = "stack", show.legend = FALSE)+
  geom_text(stat = "count", aes(x = variable, label =  value,  y = ..count../sum(..count..)*7, group = value), position = "stack", vjust = 1)+
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)+
  ylab("")
```

same output graph

You can even add a conditional line break in the labels using mutate with gsub and negative lookahead

```
df %>%
  gather(variable, value) %>% 
  mutate(label = gsub(" (?!yrs)", "\n",  value, perl = T)) %>%
  ggplot()+
  geom_bar(aes(x = variable, y = ..count../sum(..count..)*7, fill = value), color= " black", position = "stack", show.legend = FALSE)+
  geom_text(stat = "count", aes(x = variable, label =  label,  y = ..count../sum(..count..)*7, group = value), position = "stack", vjust = 1)+
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)+
  ylab("")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to replace the count_frequency (0 to 20) with percentage (as in 0-100%).

Comment: just add `scale_y_continuous(labels =  c("0%", "25%", "50%", "75%", "100%"), breaks = c(0, 5, 10, 15, 20))`. There are other ways but I trust this is easiest in current example