# R bar plot with fill

Tags: r

I am trying to create a bar plot using fill to show multiple values within one bar. I am able to get totals (y value) per the x-value, but when I try to `fill` I just get the count.

Say the example data is a data frame named `data`:

```
State           Num.Class   Num.Tweets
Pennsylvania    C           98
Pennsylvania    P           10
Pennsylvania    E           174
Pennsylvania    S           70
Texas           C           233
Texas           P           42
Texas           E           30
Texas           S           26
California      C           57
California      P           32
California      E           39
California      S           20
Massachusetts   C           23
Massachusetts   P           74
Massachusetts   E           1
Massachusetts   S           3
```

Using `ggplot` I can get the totals:

```
ggplot(data) + aes(x=State, y = Num.Tweets) + geom_col()
```

[image]

When I try `fill`ing with `gf_bar` or `ggplot() + geom_bar` I get this instead of the four counts within one bar:

```
gf_bar(~ State, fill =~ Num.Tweets, data = data)

# or
ggplot()+
     geom_bar(aes(x = data$Num.Class, fill = data$Num.Tweets), color = "black" , position = "stack", show.legend = FALSE)
```

[image]

I've been looking at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39679057/r-ggplot2-stat-count-must-not-be-used-with-a-y-aesthetic-error-in-bar-graph) and [others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46671578/r-bar-plot-with-different-variables-in-multiple-columns) but don't see what I am missing. If I shift the variables I get an error or no output.

For example:

```
gf_bar(Num.Tweets ~ State, fill =~ Num.Class, data = data)
```

returns the `Error: stat_count() must not be used with a y aesthetic.` error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data, aes(x=State, y = Num.Tweets, fill = Num.Class)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, I seem to always be missing a piece like `stat = "identity"`in this case.